# The meaning of $f\colon \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2$

Tags: notation

I know $f \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ mean that f maps each ordered pair (which contains two numbers as input) to a single number (as output). What about the $f\colon \mathbb R^2 \times  \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2 \times  \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: I know that the notation $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\times \mathbb{R}^{m}\to \mathbb{R}^{k}\times \mathbb{R}^{l}$ is generally used in the context of _implicit theorem_ _and inverse function theorem_. Maybe you can check that references.

Comment: The function takes a pair of real numbers and a real number and maps it to a pair of pairs of real numbers. This is equivalent to a map from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^4$ but there could be some context where it is natural to think of the domain and codomain this way.